# Is there a way to write a generic method that will return all objects of a type T from another object regardless of nesting level?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have an object that looks like the following:

```
MainObject
    List<NestedObject>
       NestedObject  
           List<ChildObject>
               ChildObject
               ChildObject
               ChildObject
           List<ChildObject>
               ChildObject
               ChildObject
    List<NestedObject>
       NestedObject
           List<ChildObject>
               ChildObject
           List<ChildObject>
               ChildObject
               ChildObject
       NestedObject  
           List<ChildObject>
               ChildObject
               ChildObject
```

I want a generic method that will allow me to specify ChildObject as a list of objects to return as a list. This same method would allow me to specify NestedObject as the objects to have a list of.

Is there a way to do this with Generics?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the inheritance and/or properties that make up these things, in addition to the example instance you have.

Comment: As long as the main object and all its children implement `IEnumerable` or similar, to enable recursive iteration, this should work using simply recursion and `OfType<>()`. What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Using Recursion and Reflection this should be doable but you'd have to handle strings (since they are IEnumerable) and handle infinite recursion if 2 of the objects reference eachother.

Answer (score 1):

With Linq it will be something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<T> Iterate<T>(Type type)
{
    foreach(var p in typeof(type).GetProperties()) {        
        IEnumerable<T> collection = p as IEnumerable<T>;
        if (collection != null){
            return collection 
                .OfType<T>()
                .Concat<T>(property.SelectMany(p => Iterate<T>(p)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very optimistic - you may run into cycles in the object graph, you may discover non-readable properties and a lot of other nasty stuff. I have implemented something similar a couple of years ago and it took close to 400 lines of code to handle all the edge cases. Admittedly the OP may not have to handle the general case.